# In ICS 4.0.3 using ADWLauncher EX, how can I make only three home screens instead of five?

Tags: home-screen, launcher

I just upgraded my android phone to ICS. When I had Gingerbread (2.3), I remember the option to change the number of home screens. I also had ADW launcher in 2.3 before. Now I can't find the option in ICS to change the number of home screens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Homescreen, go to *Menu*, then *Edit*. This brings you to an overview of configured home screens. Long-press the one you want to remove, and drag it to the trashbin which appears. Continue until only 3 screens are left.

Similarly, if you want to add more screens, there's one "screen" with a plus-sign ("+") in the same place. Tap that one, and you'll get an additional screen.

Comment: Accepted, 8 years later! I forgot about this question.

Comment: Thanks :D Nice you remembered. Hope it helped you all the time already ;)